# Selenium Python click on a log in with Facebook image button

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, authentication

I want to use selenium in python to automate using facebook to log in to a site.

I have managed to locate the image using xpath but nothing happens when click() is called. Here is my line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="http://kikadesigns.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/fb.jpg"]').click()
```

The site I'm trying to run the script on: http://rr2.rr.desds.com/site/login which contains the log in with Facebook image.

My full script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class FBTest2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://rr2.rr.desds.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_f_b_test2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/site/login")
        #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td > a > img").click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src,'fb.jpg')]"))
        )
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'fb.jpg')]").click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "u_0_1"))
        )
        driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    # def tearDown(self):
    #     self.driver.quit()
    #     self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes are misplaced I guess. Try the below code instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[contains(@src,"fb.jpg")]').click()
```

It works when modified and tried with Java.

Comment: It makes no difference. Still doesn't redirect me to the fb page. Will try running it on a other pc.

Comment: @AnroSwart : I have added the updated code. Please try and let me know.

Comment: I tried it on a other pc and still no luck. It doesn't successfully click the fb image. Maybe the image should not be clicked to open the link. But what then?

Comment: I have been using Firefox browser using java. It has been working all the time. Which browser and OS are you working on ? And does your code show any error  ?

Comment: I'm also using Firefox and have Win7 OS. Running it in python 3.4 with latest selenium. What I think is that the image is on another object that needs to be referenced but it is hard to see it since there is very few classnames and id's.

Comment: As I saw using firepath, the image that you are trying to click is under an 'a' element.  So, clicking on the image will redirect to the fb login page.. Nevertheless, i suggest you to use implicit wait time of 20 seconds and the above code for clicking on the element. If any issues come up ,  please add them to your question above . Also, if you can add the code you've worked upon so far, that will be helpful too..

Comment: Whosoever has downvoted the answer above, can you please give the reason why ? was it because of the misplaced quotes ?

Comment: I added my latest full script. It contains your suggestions. Was not me who downvoted.

Comment: Okay.The code seems fine. Try using latest Firefox's ESR version which you can [download from here.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/), otherwise downgrade the Firefox to a lower version, may be Firefox 20, that will do too. But, I would recommend you go to go for firefox ESR's latest version. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
enter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'fb.jpg')]")
enter.submit()
```

and make sure image on which you click points to some location